# CPSed binary tree traversal doesn't work as expected

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

My recursive version looks like

```
(struct node (val left right) #:transparent)

(define t3 (node 3 '() '()))
(define t4 (node 4 '() '()))
(define t5 (node 5 '() '()))
(define t2 (node 2 t4 t5))
(define t1 (node 1 t2 t3))
;
;     ----- 1 -----
;    |             |
; -- 2 --          3
;|       |
;4       5

(define (countv tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      0
      (+ (node-val tree)
         (countv (node-left tree))
         (countv (node-right tree)))))

(countv t1)
```

And CPSed version

```
(define (countk tree k)
  (if (null? tree)
      (k 0)
      (countk (node-left tree)
              (λ (lval)
                (countk (node-right tree)
                        (λ (rval)
                          (+ (node-val tree) lval rval)))))))

(countk t1 (λ (x) (node-val x)))
```

The result of `countv` was `15` as expected, while `countk` got `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the recursive result to the continuation:

```
(define (countk tree k)
  (if (null? tree)
      (k 0)
      (countk (node-left tree)
              (λ (lval)
                (countk (node-right tree)
                        (λ (rval)
                          (k (+ (node-val tree) lval rval))))))))
                           ^
                          Here
```

Once you remember that, you'll get a runtime error since the result isn't a tree.
This didn't happen in your code because your initial continuation was never applied to anything.

You should call it like this instead:

```
(countk t1 (λ (x) x))
```

Comment: Also use `(countk t1 (λ (x) x))` as default handling of result and not `(countk t1 (λ (x) (node-val x)))`. You could also use `(k 0) (k (countk (node-left ....`

Comment: @ReutSharabani I added the correct initial continuation, but passing the result of `countk` to the continuation `k` isn't correct.